# Multiple apps in an app

Tags: android, ios

We have recently developed an iOS and Android app for our client. Let's call the app "ABC Mobile". The app is for one of their marketing campaigns and it does a very specific function.

It is used to scan QR codes, stores credits, and then allow the users to print coupons at participating stores.

The client is planning to launch more apps for their other marketing campaigns BUT want to them to be launched inside ABC Mobile. In other words, apps within an app. The other apps could have very different functions and features, for example, a game, or a catalogue, etc.

I can understand why the client want this (e.g. they only need to market one app to their customers). I'm not very convinced their ideas would work but I need more information, from a technical standpoint, if this is possible to implement on iOS and Android?

Can you advise?

P/S: I'm not a developer

Comment: It isn't really "apps within apps". It is just one app. You can write whatever code you want to provide functions in the app. All you need is some way of navigating between those functions.

Comment: Thanks for the response. 

The reason I said it is "apps within an app" is because each app will then have its own navigation, e.g. burger menu, settings, About, etc.

Imagine all Instagram apps (IG, Boomerang, Layout, Hyperlapse) are launched from a main Instagram app. When you launch the main app, you will essentially see an 'app shelf'. And then you launch individual app from there.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Sure.  As @quidproquo says, it is still one app.  I realise that it is the client's decision not yours, but on iOS simplicity and clean navigation is a design target (See Apple's app store review guidelines and Human Interface Design guidelines), so a complex, difficult to navigate app is not desirable

Comment: Sorry, it may be clearer if you think of it like a few very different apps (e.g. WhatsApp, Uber, Spotify, etc.) put into a single main app.

Comment: I understand.  What I am saying though is that there is only *one* app; it may have screens in it that look completely different, but the user only downloads and installs a single app from the app store.  You are then effectively reproducing part of the operating system to present each of the "sub apps" (really functions) from a selection screen or shelf; It is probably a better user experience to release multiple apps, which will be smaller, self-contained and the user can manage & launch these as they wish.  You can have one app launch another using app URLs on iOS.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks mate. I think the UI/UX would be the biggest challenge as each would behave like an individual app although they all reside in the same main app.

Comment: That is of no consequence technically.  The developer has to write the code for the UI.  Whether that code is used in a stand-alone app or in one screen of a larger app makes no difference.  Where it *would* make a difference is the user experience as the one app has "modes", so if they are in a game and want to go to the QR scanner they need to navigate in the app somehow. Compare this with simply tapping the home button and selecting the QR scanner app on their device.

Comment: @Paulw11 Indeed. I'd really prefer them to be standalone apps downloaded and launched individually. Thought that would be cleaner and easier to manage.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to launch an app from another.

For Android, you need to use the Package Manager :

```
String appPackageName = "com.alexandre.myproject";

PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
Intent i = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(appPackageName);
if (i != null)
{
    context.startActivity(i);
}
```

It will open the MAIN LAUNCHER activity of the app identified by its package name.

If apps A and B have a similar theme and you change the activity name in every apps in the action bar / toolbar, the user will not realise he's swapping from A to B.

Answer (score 0):

"Apps inside apps" is still essentially one application with UI/UX that give the impression of apps within apps at the end of the day. Whether or not it is feasible, it has already been done by apps such as [101-in-1 Games](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nordcurrent.Games101) and it's iOS equivalent [101-in-1 Games](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/101-in-1-games-!/id458068537?mt=8)

Comment: Thanks -- just downloaded the game to take a look.